# Mono using statement bug with initialization

Tags: c#, mono

I think there is a bug in c# mono implementation.

```
            using (ITransactional transaction = new TransactionalContext ()) 
            using (ITransactional logTransaction = 
                new TransactionalContext(transaction.Connection ())){
                ...
            }
```

Such code doesn't call constructor of TransactionalContext and immediatelly call Dispose() on transaction variable.

Could someone confirm that?

I'm compiling this code using Mono 3.12.1 (Windows)

Some investigation:

Such code work compiled by MS compiler and fail compiled by Mono

```
public class DispTest : IDisposable
{
    private static int t = 0;

    public DispTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CONSTRUCTOR");
        this.Text = "HELLO" + t.ToString();
        t += 1;
    }

    public DispTest(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DISPOSING");
    }
}

//in main
using (DispTest t = new DispTest())
using(DispTest t2 = new DispTest(t.Text)){

}

using (DispTest t = new DispTest()){
using(DispTest t2 = new DispTest(t.Text)){
   //this code will fail too.
   }
}
```

Comment: I beg to differ. Mono has an exhaustive test suite, and I'd bet nested usings are tested. Create a small example that reproduces the issue and file a bug report.

Comment: _"Such code doesn't call constructor of TransactionalContext and immediatelly call Dispose() on transaction variable"_ -- that makes no sense. What object is used to call `Dispose()` if the constructor is never called? I suspect a case of observer error. Did you look at the compiled assembly to see what the compiler actually produced?